# imprimir sólo una fila o una columna específica de un array bidimensional

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

Si solo quiero imprimir el contenido de una fila concreta o una columna de un array bidimensional, cómo lo haría?

Se me ocurrió esto:

```
System.out.print("Las Asignaturas son: " + bi[0][0] + " " + bi[1][0] + " " + bi[2][0] + " " + bi[3][0] + "\n");
```

Pero debe haber algo más profesional, no?.

Comment: Claro, con un ciclo for

Comment: Si has tratado algo puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: con un "for" así NO chuta:   for (int i=0; i<4;i++){
      System.out.print(arrayBi[i]);     
    } Sólo quiero una fila concreta, la que yo quiera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar una columna de un modo sencillo sería con un bucle `for` indiciando la fila a mostrar. Adjunto un SSCE con la creación y como mostrar la fila:

```
int matrix[][]= new int[3][3];
        for(int i = 0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<matrix.length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = i+j;
            }
        }
        int fila = 2;
        for(int z=0;  z< matrix.length; z++) {
            System.out.println(matrix[z][fila]);
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! eso es una respuesta, si señor!!

Comment: Voy a ver si soy capaz de sacar lo mismo, pero con una columna concreta. gracias Jfhs19

Answer (score 0):

#### Obtener fila o columna especifica en array bidimensional.

Obtener columna especifica en array bidimensional, especifica la columna e iteras sobre los elementos de cada fila, ejemplo:

```
    int columna = 1; //Segunda columna
            
    for(int fila=0;  fila< matrix.length; fila++) {
        System.out.println(matrix[fila][columna]);
    }
```

Obtener fila especifica en array bidimensional, especifica la fila e iteras sobre los elementos de cada columna, ejemplo:

```
    int fila = 1; //Segunda fila
            
    for(int columna=0;  columna< matrix.length; columna++) {
        System.out.println(matrix[fila1][columna]);
    }
```